# Can't capture Click event for ImageButton - Android API Level 8

Tags: android, click, imagebutton

**Problem:** I am trying to capture click event of the ImageButton.
I am not able to capture the clickable event.I have used foll code

**Question :** Is setOnClickListener the proper way to capture ImageButton or anyother way to capture click event.
Let me know, if i can provide any more thing.

***FoodType.java***

```
public class FoodType extends Activity {

    ImageButton btnFoodType1,btnFoodType2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundleInstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundleInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.food_type);


        btnFoodType1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnFoodType1);
        btnFoodType2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnFoodType2);

        btnFoodType1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setContentView(R.layout.veg_category_type);
            }
        });

        btnFoodType2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setContentView(R.layout.non_veg_category_type);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here goes the XML for the layout used.The property for ImageButton used android:clickable="true"

***food_type.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pizza"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFoodType1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="255dp"
        android:background="@drawable/veg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFoodType2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="182dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nonveg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add android:focusable="true" in your layout to see if it make any difference..

Comment: @user493244 : I am not getting any error.The problem is control does not come in the onClick method.

Comment: Now i am able to get onClick event method.I had made some basic mistakes.Check out in solution part.Thanks @user493244 :)

Comment: if you are satisfied dont forget to accept the answers .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
The mistake i had made is:

Mistake 1: Not entered Activity details in AndroidManifest.xml.

Mistake 2: Rather calling activity directly, I was calling layout.xml.

Actually the control was not coming from Activity 1 to Activity 2,Because I have directly called the

```
setContentView(R.layout.ui2.xml);
```

Mistake 1 is solved by entering the details in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name="Sample"></activity>
```

Mistake 2 is solved by change in Activity1.java.Rather calling xml, I have called Activity2.class using Intent.

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.splash);
      entry_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEntry);
      entry_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              // Earlier mistake commented
              // setContentView(R.layout.food_type);
              Intent splashIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FoodType.class);
              startActivityForResult(splashIntent, 0);
          }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

start a new `Activity` corresponding to each of your layout when clicking one of the two `ImageButton`; don't call `setContentView()`, it won't work.

Comment: Just tested this in a sample project, calling `setContentView()` multiple times *(on button clicks)* works for me. EDIT: why is this getting +1? It is not a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in a sample project .It works fine for me.

Comment: Have you change any property ?

Comment: no i didnot change any property  i just removed the background because i dont have images.

Comment: what exactly the problem are you facing?

Comment: I am trying to capture click event of the ImageButton. I am not able to capture the clickable event.The control does not come in onClick() method.

Comment: remove background and src for buttons and try once.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this 
in XML

```
android:onClick="functionName"
```

in the code

```
public void functionName(final View view)
{
 Something();
}
```